# git как скачать изменения с сервера

Tags: git

Фрилансер создал свою ветку сделал в ней изменения, я хочу выгрузить ее на сайт что б увидеть их 
делаю `git fetch`
теперь у меня 2 ветки

```
$ git branch
  master
* outsource
```

как мне включить изменения из ветки `outsource`

вот что выдает при `git pull`

```
$ git pull

You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.outsource.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and

try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.

If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:

[branch "outsource"]
remote = <nickname>
merge = <remote-ref>

[remote "<nickname>"]
url = <url>
fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.
```

Comment: Вы хотите слить эту ветку с своим мастером?

Comment: а мне обязательно их сливать что б посмотреть изменения?

Comment: нет. не обязательно. Сделайте `git checkout outsource` и смотрите.

Comment: я приведу пример, есть файл 123.txt в нем надпись "привет", сторонний разработчик добавил "привет, я Петя" на другой ветке. как мне правильно нужно все сделать что б сначала у себя на сайте увидеть эти изменения, а потом принять решение оставлять их или нет

Comment: Вы хотите со сторонней ветки увидеть изменения на своем сайте? Нужно смотреть, как у Вас сделан деплой. Но подозреваю, что никак. Что Вы просто делаете git pull на сайте. Поэтому просто сделайте `git checkout outsource` и перезапускайте апач/нджинкс.

Comment: а как перезагрузить апач/нджинкс.?

Comment: надо создать у себя новую ветку `git checkout -b outsource` и закачать в неё изменения `git pull origin outsource`

Comment: @lexxl а зачем так сложно?

DmitriyRudnik - нужно смотреть, какая у Вас конфигурация. Я как минимум знаю десяток вариантов ответов.

Comment: непонятно, откуда у вас появилась локальная ветка `outsource`, и имеет ли она какое-либо отношение к какой-либо ветке в удалённом хранилище. приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `git remote show origin` (если удалённое хранилище подключено у вас под другим именем, не `origin`, то подставьте его). заодно уточните, как называется та ветка в удалённом хранилище, которую вы хотите посмотреть. внести изменения в вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

У вас в репозитории могут быть созданы десятки и даже больше веток, но находиться вы можете только на какой-то одной из них.

Поэтому "переключиться" на другую ветку, **чтобы посмотреть** изменения сделанные аутсорсером в другой ветке -- можно, но обычно предполагается, что после завершения работы над какой-то фичей (произведённые в отдельной ветке) изменения вливаются в основную ветку (для вас это ветка master).

Переключение на ветку (она у вас уже создана) выполняется через `git checkout outsource` (вы переходите на последний коммит в этой ветке).

Если вы хотите подтянуть в ветку outsorce свежие коммиты, то находясь на вете outsource вам нужно дать команду `git pull origin outsource`.

Всё вышеописанное рассчитано на среднестатистический вариант, потому что в комментариях вам правильно заметили, что имя локальной ветки может не совпадать с удалённым хранилищем и вообще, похоже, что у вас сразу несколько связанных вопросов.